# Coldfusion Spreadsheet cell formatting

Tags: excel, coldfusion, spreadsheet

I need to generate excel spreadsheet with coldfusion 10 from a query. So far its working fine except the headers of the table. They are dynamically generated [month Year] December 2012. When I add a header column I get it in the date format like '01/12/2013'. There are other types of date formatting and other types of cell formatting. How do I force a cell to format as a string. Kind of when you add single quotation.

This is my code:

```
<cfset VARIABLES.vcFilename = "billtotals_" & DateFormat(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & "-" & TimeFormat(Now(), "HHmmss") & ".xls">
<cfset VARIABLES.sheet = SpreadSheetNew( "Summary" )>
<cfset VARIABLES.columns = arrayToList(GetBillPremTotals.getMeta().getColumnLabels())>
<cfset SpreadSheetAddRow( VARIABLES.sheet,VARIABLES.columns)>

<cfset format1 = StructNew()>
<cfset format1.bold = "true">
// tried this just for kicks doesn't work <cfset format1.dataformat = "'">
// tried this converts to a number <cfset format1.dataformat = "text">
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatRow(VARIABLES.sheet, format1, 1)> 

<cfset SpreadSheetAddRows(VARIABLES.sheet,GetBillPremTotals)>

<cfset SpreadSheetAddRows(VARIABLES.sheet,GetBillPremGrandTotals)>
<cfset VARIABLES.sheetAsBinary = SpreadSheetReadBinary(VARIABLES.sheet)>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#Chr(34)##VARIABLES.vcFilename##Chr(34)#">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#VARIABLES.sheetAsBinary#" reset="true">
```

This is a table with data from query analyzer, displays fine in the browser in html format

```
No          November 2012                           December 2012                           January 2013                            February 2013
----------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
25          60117.56000                             61515.17000                             60791.62000                             60745.29000
28          1564.69000                              1564.69000                              1564.69000                              1590.44000
30          110599.11000                            173954.08000                            178064.11000                            172892.65000
```

Thank you in advance,
Gena

Comment: You didn't show the code that you claim to generate strings such as December 2012.  What is that code?  What happens if you run it and output the result in a browser?

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but IIRC, to [format as text](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6747.html) use either `dataFormat="text"` or `dataFormat="@"` , then apply the value.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk I updated my question with the output from query analyzer

Comment: @Leigh I tried both text and @. They both format headers as numbers.

Comment: Try applying the format *before* you add the column header row. If its auto-converting the value to a date, applying the format after the fact will not help.

Comment: @Leigh Applying before does not format at all.

Comment: Unless something is broken in CF10, it should work. Unfortunately I am not near a CF10 machine to test/work up an example. Hopefully someone else will chime in ...

Comment: The output from query analyser is not necessarily the same as what is happening in your app.  If you use SpreadSheetSetCellValue with a value of 'Decemeber 2012', what appears in your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick.

```
<cfset format1.dataformat = "mmmm yyyy">
```

Comment: You should mark it as correct to make things easier for the next person with the same issue.